# TimePicker reset bug. Any workaround?

Tags: android

I found some problem for TimePicker widget. After user change time in widget setHour and setMinute methods not works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);

                Log.v(TAG, "onClick: " + hour + "=>" + mTimePicker.getHour());
                Log.v(TAG, "onClick: " + minute + "=>" + mTimePicker.getMinute());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Step for reproduce:

1. Run app (my time: 13:21)
2. Change time on the Widget (21:21)
3. Tap on the Reset button

Result:time not reset to 13:21

Log:

> 03-30 13:18:05.765 30923-30923/ru.neverdark.timepickerproblem
>   V/MainActivity: onClick: 13=>21 03-30 13:18:05.765
>   30923-30923/ru.neverdark.timepickerproblem V/MainActivity: onClick:
>   18=>18

Any workaround for this problem?

Same bug I found in Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208180 but in SDK25 not fixed...

Demo project on the github: https://github.com/yankovskiy/TimePickerProblem

Comment: I am just a newbie at android, but it looks like you might be trying to set it to the current time.  I am using if fine, but here is some of the code which might help you.  If not just disregard this comment, you probably know more about this than I do.

Comment: Yes, me need "reset" functionality for current widget. Reset by user action. For DatePicker I no have problem with the similar code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the MCVE that you supplied. I can change the time and reset it many times and everything works as expected. Is there something that I am missing? I haven't changed anything in the code. I have not been able to duplicate the problem on an emulator at API 24 and one at API 17.

Comment: Which `Locale` is the crash occurring on?

Comment: @Cheticamp tested on the API23 and API16 with Russian and English locale. If you are test project from github - remove or comment call fixValues()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have to admit, this is not my proudest code.

But as a workaround you can have this:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        fixValues();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mTimePicker.setHour(currentHour);
            mTimePicker.setMinute(currentMinute);
        } else {
            mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(currentHour);
            mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(currentMinute);
        }
    }
});

private void fixValues() {
    // bug is not reproducible in APIs 24 and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) return;
    try {
        int hour, minute;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            hour = mTimePicker.getHour();
            minute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
        } else {
            hour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
            minute = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        }

        Field mDelegateField = mTimePicker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDelegate");
        mDelegateField.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> clazz;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate");
        } else {
            clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate");
        }
        Field mInitialHourOfDayField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mInitialHourOfDay");
        Field mInitialMinuteField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mInitialMinute");
        mInitialHourOfDayField.setAccessible(true);
        mInitialMinuteField.setAccessible(true);
        mInitialHourOfDayField.setInt(mDelegateField.get(mTimePicker), hour);
        mInitialMinuteField.setInt(mDelegateField.get(mTimePicker), minute);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tested on APIs 21, 22 and 23.

Bug is not reproducible in APIs 24, 25.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    checkMark = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13)                            ;
    checkMark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)                                       ;
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
            timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID_ON:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
            timePickerListenerOn, hour, minute,false);
    }
    return null;
    }
```

How about this?

```
picker.setCurrentHour(date.getHours())
picker.setCurrentMinute(date.getMinutes())
```

Comment: Have you made any progress with your issue?  If not, I did something similar which may help you if I understand what you are trying to do.  I needed to use the time picker to select user selectable times, including the current time.  I had a button on an activity, which called the time picker on a fragment, where the user selected a time which was passed back to the calling activity.  If you think this will help, let me know and I will get some code to you